# Minimum Cost Path with Left, Right, Bottom and Up moves allowed

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, dijkstra

**Problem Statement:**
Given a square grid of size `N`, each cell of which contains integer cost which represents a cost to traverse through that cell, we need to find a path from top left cell to bottom right cell by which the total cost incurred is minimum.
From the cell `(i,j)` we can go `(i,j-1)`, `(i, j+1)`, `(i-1, j)`, `(i+1, j)`.

**Note:** It is assumed that negative cost cycles do not exist in the input matrix.

Below is the code that I have written:

```
class Coordinate {
    int x;
    int y;

    public Coordinate(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + x;
        result = prime * result + y;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Coordinate other = (Coordinate) obj;
        if (x != other.x)
            return false;
        if (y != other.y)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}

public class MinCostPath {

    public static int minimumCostPath(int[][] grid) {
        int R = grid.length;
        int C = grid[0].length;
        int[][] dist = new int[R][C];
        for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) {
                dist[i][j] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }
        }
        dist[0][0] = grid[0][0];
        Queue<Coordinate> q = new LinkedList<>();

        q.add(new Coordinate(0, 0));
        int[] x = { -1, 1, 0, 0 };
        int[] y = { 0, 0, 1, -1 };
        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            Coordinate current = q.poll();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                int xi = current.getX() + x[i];
                int yi = current.getY() + y[i];

                if (isSafe(xi, yi, R, C)) {
                    if (dist[xi][yi] > dist[current.getX()][current.getY()] + grid[xi][yi]) {
                        dist[xi][yi] = dist[current.getX()][current.getY()] + grid[xi][yi];
                        Coordinate c = new Coordinate(xi, yi);
                        if (!q.contains(c))
                            q.add(c);
                    }

                }
            }

        }

        return dist[R - 1][C - 1];
    }

    private static boolean isSafe(int xi, int yi, int r, int c) {
        return (xi >= 0) && (xi < r) && (yi >= 0) && (yi < c);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] grid = { { 9, 4, 9, 9 }, { 6, 7, 6, 4 }, { 8, 3, 3, 7 }, { 7, 4, 9, 10 } };
        System.out.println(minimumCostPath(grid));

    }

}
```

It gives 'Runtime Error:Time Limit Exceeded' Error

Below is an article from geeksforgeeks that has the solution.
[Minimum Cost Path Problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-cost-path-left-right-bottom-moves-allowed/)

What I am not able to understand is why my code is giving 'Time Limit Exceeded' Error while the solution mentioned in the article is working. To my understanding, both the solutions are doing exactly the same thing.

Please help me understand the difference and what optimization is needed in the code that I have written. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The error is not generated by the code you posted.  Find where the error is generated and increase the time limit.

Answer (score 0):

> what optimization is needed in the code

The problem needs to be reformulated so you can apply the Dijkstra algorithm ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm )

That algorithm assumes the links are costed, rather than the nodes ( cells ).  Consider two adjacent cells with traversal costs c and d.  Travelling from the first to the second adds cost d.  Travelling from the second to the first adds cost c.  So you can connect the two cells with two unidirectional links of cost c and d.  The Dijkstra algorithm will give you the correct cost when the entire path is travelled, minus the the traversal cost of the first cell - which is a constant and can therefor be ignored when finding the optimal path.

I use the boost graph implementation of Dijkstra, which is fast and well tested ( https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/graph/doc/dijkstra_shortest_paths.html ).  The API is a challenge if you haven't used the boost library before, so I use a C++ style wrapper to simplify coding ( https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder )

Here is the output from PathFinder on the sample problem you posted

```
C:\Users\James\code\PathFinder\bin>mazes ..\dat\vivekkumar.txt
Mazes
cellcosts
s9 4 9 9
6 7 6 4
8 3 3 7
7 4 9 e10
4 by 4

0 -> 1 -> 5 -> 9 -> 10 -> 11 -> 15 ->

+---+---+---+---+
| s   *         |
+   +   +   +   +
|     *         |
+   +   +   +   +
|     *   *   * |
+   +   +   +   +
|             e |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the approach. I still want to understand why the code in the article is working, while my code doesn't . For me looks like both the codes are doing same thing just in different ways. I am using condition `if (!q.contains(c))` as I am storing the distance in a separate matrix, while the code in the article is removing it from priority queue after checking the condition `if (dist[rows][cols] != Integer.MAX_VALUE)`. Then why my code is giving Time Limit Exceeded error while code in the article is working. Please help me understand the flaw in my code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your implementation that you are trying to use Breadth First Search instead of Dijkstra which is the right approach to solve this.

You need to use a priority queue and a map to trace your path.

Also for BFS typically you don't need to do `if (! q.contains(node))` that actually unnecessarily consumes time.

Comment: The condition if (! q.contains(node)) is to avoid reprocessing the same cell unnecessarily. If you look at the solution in article mentioned, It does the same thing in different manner If Cell is already been reached once, remove it from priority queue `if (dist[rows][cols] != Integer.MAX_VALUE)`  then `pq.remove(adj)`. I am also doing the sane thing in another way. yet my code is giving Time Limit Exceeded error while the code in the article is working.

Comment: @VivekKumar  I don't know the exact reason why you added .contains check. But it seems you are using BFS and BFS is not right for this problem.